# ZF2 versioning of assets to avoid caching of old files

Tags: gulp, zend-framework2

I have a ZF2 project where I generate, minify, etc... my assets via gulp. For example I generate a styles.css file which gets included with the ZF2 headlink view helper:

```
echo $this->headLink()->appendStylesheet($this->baasePath('assets/css/styles.css));
```

Now I have the problem, that the file gets cached by the browser and does't notify any changes. Does anyone know a way to handle that? Maybe add a version number to the generated css file, but then I really don't want to edit all the ZF2 templates which inlcude that file.

Thanks for any reply.

Answer (score 0):

There's a load of ways to do this, but one option is to use Assetic - a well known asset manager package. Tere's a few ZF2 modeules to help integrate this library into the framework too. A quick google search throws up some:

```
https://github.com/magnetronnie/zf2-assetic-module
https://github.com/kriswallsmith/assetic/
```

This module will help manage assets such as CSS/JS, and also has some "cache busting" features where by you can change the url based upon the file modification date to ensure if changes when ever the file is re-downloaded by the browser.